# Load package contents without using their name afterwards

Tags: go

Is there a way to load the contents of a package in go without needing to use the package name? For example, in Python you can do:

```
from somepackage import *
# access function from somepackage foo
foo()
```

I would like to do that in Go. I tried:

```
import _ "path/to/my/package"
```

but it didn't work. I'm having trouble articulating myself to find the solution online, if there is one.

Comment: Note that this is extremely uncommon and you won't find a lot of Go code that does this in the wild.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Import declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations)
>
> If an explicit period (.) appears instead of a name, all the package's
>   exported identifiers declared in that package's package block will be
>   declared in the importing source file's file block and must be
>   accessed without a qualifier.

Use a period (.) instead of a name. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    . "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Now()) // time.Now()
}
```

Output:

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Comment: Well, I stand corrected, I should have read the spec with more attention. Thanks!

Comment: @rofls: Really, ready to quit Go over this? If this is such an important feature for you and you plan to use it often, I highly recommend you rethink how you approach programming, because importing other packages into your local namespace is something you should generally avoid. Remember that you can always give local names to imported identifiers for convenience, e.g. `var now = time.Now`.

Comment: Thanks @Aedolon, but I was just kidding about quitting Go. I'm only using it in one place, and I understand it's pretty bad practice in general.